# Performing query inside active row array

Tags: php, mysqli

Basically i'm using an mySQLi wrapper i've found online and while trying to use it i've came across a problem i can't see to get past, basically, i'm performing this.

```
<?php 
    $res = $DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
    while($row = $DB->Fetch()) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $functions->checkStatus($row['arowhere']); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
      }
?>
```

So when i'm trying to do this `$functions->checkStatus($row['arowhere']);` **it performs a new query inside this function** on my table row, it's changing the **latest query** which is being used for the `while($row = $DB->Fetch()) {`

```
public function Query($SQL) {
        $this->SQL = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($SQL);
        $this->Result = $this->mysqli->query($SQL);

        if ($this->Result == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
             die('Problem with Query: ' . $this->SQL);
        }
}

public function Fetch() {
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->Result);
}
```

Is there a solution or maybe someone point me in the correct direction so i can avoid this please.

Comment: Yes, don't use a wrapper like this .. There is absolutely no reason to use this, the simple PDO/MySQLi objects does the same without all the headaches ..

Comment: @dbf so you'd recommend me recoding my complete application ?

Comment: I'm recommending not to use the overhead ;) If it involves recoding your application then that is up to you. Just write a little reference guide. One small code of this example with your wrapper class and one example with just the pure mysqli functionality. If the wrapper class does not add any advantages (but disadvantages), then you know your choice ;)

Comment: can't you use a `JOIN` to get all values with one query?

Comment: @CurtisCrewe I think your choice for using this wrapper was for writing less code right? And I think the wrapper class uses a singleton approach for the database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe such a wrapper can be found online. As a matter of fact, it's **completely, ultimately unusable.**

Doing `mysqli->real_escape_string($SQL);` makes absolutely no sense. It won't protect your query from injection yet it will spoil whatever complex query. As soon as you will try to run a query with WHERE condition it will die from error.

And the following line is also wrong

```
die('Problem with Query: ' . $this->SQL);
```

as it's not showing you neither error nor file and line number.

And *least* this wrapper's problem is one you face - it is using *internal* variable to hold the result, while it should just **return** it.

[A real mysqli wrapper is SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql), which lets you to add whatever dynamical data via placeholders.

With SafeMysql your code would work:

```
<?php 
    $res = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
    while($row = $db->fetch($res)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $functions->checkStatus($row['arowhere']); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the rows and add them to a temporary array.  You could then reference the rows via this array after other queries have been made.  This could have memory implications if there are too many rows being returned by the query, so be careful.

```
<?php 
$res = $DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `table`");

$rows = array();
while($row = $DB->Fetch()) {
    array_push( $rows, $row );
}

foreach( $rows as $row ){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $functions->checkStatus($row['arowhere']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}
unset( $rows ); // destroys the temporary array, freeing the memory it consumed
?>
```